# ActionView::MissingTemplate error when using modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I'm using a versioned API design from [this RailsCasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning) and it's working great, except my jbuilder templates aren't rendering.

Here's my controller code:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class LocationsController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

      def index
        @locations = Location.all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And my jbuilder file is at `app/views/api/v1/locations/index.json.jbuilder`

I get the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template api/v1/locations/index, 
api/v1/api/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], 
:variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. 
Searched in: * "/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/app/views"
```

**EDIT:** And here's the code in my `routes.rb` file:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :locations,   only: [ :index ]
  end
end
```

Any ideas how I could debug this? Why are the files in the `api` folder not being found by Rails? Thanks!

Comment: I think in rails 4 you have to do `respond_with @locations` in your controller.

Comment: Can you show your `routes.rb` file that relate to this controller?

Comment: @Anthony I believe that just calls `to_json` (or is it `as_json`?) on the object, as calling that doesn't actually render the jbuilder template.

Comment: Looks like nothing wrong with this code, but in error message `api/v1/api/index` appear to not in usual template path. Is there other spacial settings in your code? And is this controller in `app/controllers/api/v1/` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue all the time. It can sometimes be a typo or error raised in the actual code within the json templates. Try commenting out all the lines in the index.json.jbuilder file, reload, work? Try uncommenting a line at a time. I haven't found a solution for better debugging this issue with jbuilder... yet.

Answer (score 0):

in routes you should remove the defaults: { format: :json }

Comment: Even if this is probably true (not a ruby expert here), you should try to extend your answer with more information to provide more content to the OP.